# Vlookup works in excel sheet but showing error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
 'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A19,Sheet2!$A$2:$BA$26,MATCH("New Ratio number",Sheet2!$1:$1,0),FALSE)),VLOOKUP($A19,Sheet3!$A$1:$AH$465,MATCH("Coverage (Number)",Sheet3!$1:$1,0),FALSE),VLOOKUP($A19,Sheet2!$A$2:$BA$26,MATCH("New Ratio number",Sheet2!$1:$1,0),FALSE))"
```

Coverage (Number) and New ratio Number are column names (I doubt that column names are a probblem)
The Vlookup when I insert in a cell it is working but it is showing an syntax error in VBA. Also I have checked  other formula which worked means there is no problem in lastrow or any other statement in the code. Can anyone point out the problem please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double up your double quotes around strings.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A19,Sheet2!$A$2:" & _
    "$BA$26,MATCH(""New Ratio number"",Sheet2!$1:$1,0),FALSE)),VLOOKUP($A19,Sheet3!$A$1:" & _
    "$AH$465,MATCH(""Coverage (Number)"",Sheet3!$1:$1,0),FALSE),VLOOKUP($A19,Sheet2!$A$2:" & _
    "$BA$26,MATCH(""New Ratio number"",Sheet2!$1:$1,0),FALSE))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your double quotes with an extra double quote:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A19,Sheet2!$A$2:$BA$26,MATCH(""New Ratio number"",Sheet2!$1:$1,0),FALSE)),VLOOKUP($A19,Sheet3!$A$1:$AH$465,MATCH(""Coverage (Number)"",Sheet3!$1:$1,0),FALSE),VLOOKUP($A19,Sheet2!$A$2:$BA$26,MATCH(""New Ratio number"",Sheet2!$1:$1,0),FALSE))"
```